# Normal instance method calls within a clojure doto

Tags: swing, clojure

I'm setting up a swing UI in clojure and have a block like:

```
  (doto main-frame
    (.setUndecorated true)
    (.setExtendedState Frame/MAXIMIZED_BOTH)
    (.setDefaultCloseOperation JFrame/EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
    (.setVisible true)
    )
```

But now I want to call

```
(.setBackground (.getContentPane main-frame) Color/BLACK)
```

before I set the frame visible, is there a nicer way to do this than ending the doto and using the (.instanceMember instance args*) syntax?

Comment: why can't the call to ``(.setBackground ...)`` just go before the ``(doto)`` ?

Comment: It can, but that always forces one to always have a def for the JFrame rather than being able to use the constructor as the first argument to the doto like: `(doto (JFrame.) (.setVisible true))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want a single `doto`, then maybe this will do:

```
(doto main-frame
  (.setUndecorated true)
  (.setExtendedState Frame/MAXIMIZED_BOTH)
  (.setDefaultCloseOperation JFrame/EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
  (-> (.getContentPane) (.setBackground Color/BLACK))
  (.setVisible true))
```

The above relies on the fact that `doto` is not confined to Java methods, it just inserts its first argument (evaluated) as first argument of every form that follows.

I'd go with ending the `doto` though as the above is not very readable. Alternatively, maybe just define a `set-background-on-content-pane` function (that obviously takes the `main-frame`) and use that in the `doto`:

```
(defn set-bg-on-frame [fr color] (.setBackground (.getContentPane fr) color))

(doto main-frame
   .
   .
   .
   (set-bg-on-frame Color/BLACK)
   (.setVisible true))
```

Comment: Thanks, the `set-background-on-content-pane` option seems cleanest.

Comment: @Baxter Renamed in the example to set-bg-on-frame. Function naming is an art :-)

Comment: Ha, much more finger-friendly too, It's a shame there's not a more general construct for popping out of or nesting a `(doto)` ooh, actually:      `(.. getContentPane (setBackground Color/BLACK))`   seems to play nice with the doto argument insertion.

Comment: Or perhaps more generally `(-> .getContentPane (.setBackground Color/BLACK)`

Comment: @Baxter: Right, I missed this simplification! - will edit to incorporate.